# Error in installing mysqldb in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to install mysql db in python, but i am unable to do so. I have installed set up tools and downloaded python mysqldb. when i am trying to do **Setup.py install** in command prompt it is showing error " Unable to open Url". I dont have internet connection to my PC.

After doing this when i am giving import mysqldb in python shell
its giving me error as **no module named Connector**

Can any one help in installing of Mysqldb in python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am working on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing via the Binary:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python